# Surjectivity of multiplication by $n$ on the separable points of an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties, galois-cohomology, separable-extension

> Is there an abelian variety $A$ over a field $k$, such that $A(k^{\rm sep})$ is not a divisible group?

The motivation of my question is the following : if $L$ is any algebraically closed field, then $A(L)$ is a divisible group, that is the multiplication map $ [n] : A(L) \to A(L)$ is a surjective group morphism, for every $n \neq 0$ (see [corollary 5.10](https://www.math.ru.nl/~bmoonen/BookAV/Isogs.pdf)). But if $L$ is only separably closed (e.g. $L = \Bbb F_p(T)^{\rm sep}$), it might not be true anymore ; however I have no counterexample. According to the cited reference, "if the ground field $k'$ is only assumed to be separably closed then it is not true in general that $X(k')$ is a divisible group", but no example is given.

If one can find a one-dimensional abelian variety $A$ such that $A(k^{\rm sep})$ is not divisible (in particular, $A$ is an elliptic curve), then I don't understand how one gets the surjective map $[n] : A(k^{\rm sep}) \to A(k^{\rm sep})$ at the beginning of the section 2 [here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=mwBP2G1TOmUC&pg=PA174#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

[My ultimate goal is to get a long exact sequence in Galois cohomology for abelian varities over $\Bbb F_p(T)$.]

Comment: In the section 2 of the quoted document, $n$ is assumed to be coprime with the characteristic of $k$, so $[n]$ might still be surjective over the separable closure of $k$, but I am not sure why (probably using the separability of $[n]$).

Comment: In the case where $n = p = \mathrm{char}(k)$ and $k$ is a global field, it is not clear how to prove that \Sha(E / k)[p] is finite, since there is no obvious exact sequence involving the p-Selmer group of E (which should be finite)

Comment: In "Lectures on curves and Jacobians over function fields", §5.2.1, Ulmer points out a short exact sequence of sheaves in the _flat topology_ $0 \to E[n] \to E \overset{[\cdot n]}{\to} E \to 0$ where $E$ is an elliptic curve over $k(C)$, and $k$ finite, and $n$ _any_ integer (not necessarily coprime to the characteristic $p$ of $k$). However, in §5.1.1 he indicates that if $p \mid n$, the sequence is not exact in the _étale_ topology…

Comment: The surjectivity of the map $[n] : A(k^{\rm sep}) \to A(k^{\rm sep})$ when $n$ is coprime to the characteristic of $k$ follows from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845819, since $[n] : A \to A$ is étale.

Comment: @Watson: to add to my second comment above, it is indeed not obvious that Sha(E / k)[p] is finite when k = F_p(T) as mentioned in Ulmer's "Lectures on curves and Jacobians over function fields": finiteness of the p-part was first proven by Milne [Elements of order p in the Tate-Šafarevič group. Bull. London Math. Soc., 2:293–296, 1970].

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616121. Moreover, in Geer, Moonen's "ABELIAN VARIETIES", 5.6 shows that for an isogeny, being separable or étale is the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\F}{\Bbb F}
$
After thinking again to this question, I finally came up with a counter-example myself.

Let me first notice that whenever $n$ is an integer coprime to the characteristic of a field $K$, then the multiplication-by-2 map
$$ [n] : E(K^s) \to E(K^s)$$
is surjective on the points of an elliptic curve $E$ with coordinates in the separable closure $K^s$ of $K$. This is because under the coprimality assumption, $[n] : E \to E$ is an étale morphism (then apply [Surjective étale morphisms on points.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845819)).

---

However, this fails if $n$ is no longer coprime to $\mathrm{char}(K)$. Namely, let $E$ be the elliptic curve given by $y^2 + xy = x^3 + t^4$ over $K = \F_2(t)$. We prove that the multiplication-by-2 map
$$ [2] : E(K^s) \to E(K^s)$$
is not surjective on the separable closure $K^s$ of $K$.

Let $Q = (t, t^2) \in E(K) \subset E(K^s)$. Let $P = (x, y) \in E(\overline K)$ be such that $Q = 2P$.
Then we get (see Silverman's book AEC)

$$t = x(2P) = \dfrac{x^4 - t^4}{x^2},$$
which implies $x^4 - t x^2 - t^4 = 0$.
If we prove that the polynomial
$$f(z) := z^4 + t z^2 + t^4 \in \F_2(t)[z] = K[z]$$
is irreducible, then from $f(x) = 0$ and $f' = 0$ we deduce that $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K$ and is not separable. Hence $x \not \in K^s$ and $P \not \in E(K^s)$, which shows that $ [2] : E(K^s) \to E(K^s)$
is not surjective.

---

It remains to prove that  $f(z) := z^4 + t z^2 + t^4 \in \F_2(t)[z] = K[z]$ is irreducible.
First, by Gauss' lemma, $f$ is irreducible over $K$ iff it is irreducible over $\F_2[t]$. Then, observe that $f$ has no roots : if $z(t) \in \F_2[t]$ is a root of $f$, then plugging $t=1$ yields $z(1)^4 + z(1)^2 + 1 = 0$ but this is impossible since $z(1) \in \F_2$.

Then assume $z^4 + t z^2 + t^4 = (az^2 + bz + c)(\alpha z^2 + \beta z + \gamma)$. Then $a, \alpha \in  \F_2[t]^{\times} = \{1\}$ and
$$z^4 + z^3(b + \beta) + z^2(\gamma + c + b \beta) + z(b \gamma + c \beta) + c \gamma    \;=\;     z^4 + t z^2 + t^4.$$

This gives $\beta = -b$ and so $b(\gamma - c) = 0$. The case $b=0$ would imply $(t+c)c = t^4$ but again evaluating at $t=1$ makes it impossible to happen. So $\gamma = c$ and we are left with $b \beta = t = -b^2$, and for degree reasons, this cannot happen either.

All in all, we proved that the above factorization is impossible. Therefore $z^4 + t z^2 + t^4$ is indeed irreducible over $\F_2[t]$, and this concludes the proof.
$\hspace{4cm} \square$

Comment: My sincere rewelcome in TeX.SE. and my best greetings. Also I am in TeX.SE.

Comment: @Sebastiano : thanks ;-)